# Issues with QDataStream using QString and QByteArray

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qbytearray, qdatastream

```
QByteArray ba;
QDataStream ds(&ba,QIODevice::WriteOnly);
ds<<quint8(1)<<quint16(2)<<quint32(3);  //1+2+4
qDebug()<<"size:"<<ba.size();   // 7
```

I use `QDataStream` to write 3 number, ba.size() is 7, but I'm confused about this:

```
QByteArray ba;
QDataStream ds(&ba,QIODevice::WriteOnly);
QString s="a";
ds<<quint8(1)<<quint16(2)<<quint32(3)<<s;  //1+2+4+a
qDebug()<<"size:"<<ba.size();   // 13
```

If a QString's `size` is 1, ba's size plus 6, why is that? `sizeof(QString)` is 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's analyze the difference between both impressions:

```
"\x01\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03"
"\x01\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00""a"
-----------------------------------------------------
                              x00\x00\x00\x02\x00""a
```

And for that, let's review the [source code](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/tools/qstring.cpp#n9743):

```
QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &out, const QString &str)
{
    if (out.version() == 1) {
        out << str.toLatin1();
    } else {
        if (!str.isNull() || out.version() < 3) {
            if ((out.byteOrder() == QDataStream::BigEndian) == (QSysInfo::ByteOrder == QSysInfo::BigEndian)) {
                out.writeBytes(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(str.unicode()), sizeof(QChar) * str.length());
            } else {
                QVarLengthArray<ushort> buffer(str.length());
                const ushort *data = reinterpret_cast<const ushort *>(str.constData());
                for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
                    buffer[i] = qbswap(*data);
                    ++data;
                }
                out.writeBytes(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(buffer.data()), sizeof(ushort) * buffer.size());
            }
        } else {
            // write null marker
            out << (quint32)0xffffffff;
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

That method uses the `writeBytes()` method, 
and according to the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html#writeBytes):

> **QDataStream &QDataStream::writeBytes(const char *s, uint len)**
>
> Writes the **length specifier len** and the **buffer s** to the stream and
>   returns a reference to the stream.
>
> The len is serialized as a quint32, followed by len bytes from s. Note
>   that the data is not encoded.

That is, apart from writing the data, write the length of the text in `quint32` format (4 bytes) and the length of the buffer is equal to `sizeOf(QChar)` x `length of the QString`.

Taking into account in it we can understand the result better:

```
      x00\x00\x00\x02          \x00""a
      ---------------          -------
  numbers of bytes of buffer    buffer
```

In general you can use the following formula to calculate the size of the stored data:

```
length stored data = 4 + 2 x length of string
```

Comment: Thanks, really helpful and impressive

Answer (score 1):

By checking [Qt Documentation for QDatastream](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html#details), how strings are stored and retreived:

> a char * string is written as a 32-bit integer equal to the length of
>   the string including the '\0' byte, followed by all the characters of
>   the string including the '\0' byte. When reading a char * string, 4
>   bytes are read to create the 32-bit length value, then that many
>   characters for the char * string including the '\0' terminator are
>   read.

So in your case 32 bit for length of the string + 1 Byte for "a" + 1 byte for \0, which sums to 6 bytes.